# Induced voltage in twisted pair located close to AC conductor

Tags: induction

<s>Anyone with MathJax-knowledge, feel free to clean up my formulas below.</s> Thanks Hearth!

Owing to certain circumstances I can't go into details to, I have to place my DC supply wires close to an AC conductor (a busbar actually).

Twisted pair does not mean CAT5/6/whatever and is certainly not Ethernet.

I need to calculate how much voltage the AC conductor can induce in my DC supply, and from there, how much twisting the DC cables would alleviate the situation. The AC phase and neutral are located very far from each other and cannot be moved. Frequency is either 50 or 60 Hz mains.

I realize I have not calculated these things since collage a long time ago so I need a brush-up on the subject.

Assuming the AC conductor have infinite length, the magnetic field around it according to the right hand rule would be:

$$ B = \mu_0 \cdot \dfrac{I}{2\pi r} $$

The victim of said AC magnetic flux would be my DC wire. The area occupied by the victim inside the flux area is the <s>DC wire diameter</s> distance between the DC wires times its length.

$$A = d · L$$

Induced voltage is the cable:

$$ E = d \cdot L \cdot \mu_0 \cdot \dfrac{dB}{dt} $$

$$\frac{dB}{dt} = 2πf · I · cos(2π · 60 · t)$$

Round up cos() to 1...

$$\frac{dB}{dt} \approx 2πf · I$$

Ok, assume the DC lines aren't routed together for a starting point and put the DC <s>conductor diameter</s> cable separation at 1 mm and 1 meter length, 5 cm spacing between AC busbar and DC line and 1 kA(rms) of AC current. I end up with 4 mT(rms) from the AC current inducing:

$$E = \frac{d · l · μ_0 · f · I}{r} = \frac{1\ \mathrm{mm} · 1\ \mathrm{m} · 1.26×10^{-6}\ \mathrm{\frac{H}{m}} · 60\ \mathrm{Hz} · 1\ \mathrm{kA}}{0.05\ \mathrm{cm}} = 1.5\ \mathrm{mV(rms)}$$

This sounds low.
Am I fooling myself that current is high hence large induced voltage when in fact the area is very small, frequency is low and permeability in vacuum is 10^-6, all of them working in my favor here?

Are my calculations somewhat correct? If yes, no need for twisting of wires. If no, how would I go about calculating or estimating how much difference twisting the DC supply cables would make?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRoNWZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: B=u0 x I/(2 x pi x r). -->  `\$  B = \mu_0 \cdot  \dfrac{I}{2\pi r}  \$`  --> \$  B = \mu_0 \cdot  \dfrac{I}{2\pi r}\$  $$$$ I din't follow this bit: *"The area affected by the magnetic flux would be my DC wire diameter times length"*

Comment: “Assuming the AC conductor have infinite length” // Side note: that equation (obtained from Biot-Savart’s law or Ampère’s law without Maxwell’s correction) is derived additionally assuming the current is constant (DC). For time-varying currents, in general we need [Jefimenko’s equations](en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations). But for low-frequency alternating currents (which is the case for AC mains with negligible harmonics), we may neglect the retarded time and skin effect and so your equation is a reasonable approximation. I’m saying this as a reminder, in case you forgot it.

Comment: Yep, for 1m length, DC conductors spaced 1mm apart, spaced 5cm from a conductor carrying 1kA at 60Hz, I get a worst case mutual inductance of 4nH, so \$|V|=\omega M I\$ = 1.5mV.  If you twist them you would get even less.  Note you should at least consider the effect of harmonics as the coupling is greater.

Comment: @AlejandroNava Thanks! Do you have a rule of thumb when the DC approximation is good enough? Remember this is engineering, not science...

Comment: @Tesla23 Calculating the mutual inductance and just multiply with frequency and current sounds like a different but easier approach to get the same result. I'll think about it next time.

Comment: @winny I’m not that involved in electromagnetic theory (Maxwell’s equations, Jefimenko’s, retarded potentials, continuity, etc.), but I’ve read the DC approximation is okay for up to 100 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, close proximity to a mains AC line is more likely to cause capacitatively coupled noise than inductively coupled. This is especially true if the DC load is small, i.e. high impedance.

Inductive coupling requires a high mutual inductance.

According to [this calculator](https://www.qsl.net/in3otd/ind1calc.html) a pair of 10 meter diameter loops of 5 mm wire with 100% coupling coefficient will only have 48.2 uH of mutual inductance. With 60 Hz mains, that works out to only 18 mOhm of inductive impedance.

The load on the power line and the inductive impedance of the line form a voltage divider. So, for example, with the AC powering a 6 Ohm load, there will only be about 0.003 times the AC voltage induced in the mutual inductance. You mention 1 kA current, so your load may be significantly less than the example 6 Ohm, and that will tend to increase the inductive noise.

But is there actually that much mutual inductance? Since AC wiring tends to have line and neutral in close proximity, even though not twisted pair, the magnetic fields will tend to cancel out. In your case, the line and neutral are not close, but the DC lines *are*. The proximity of the victim lines will serve to ensure low mutual inductance with the AC.

As far as capacitatively coupled noise goes, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOoyrsi6ctk) shows 2V noise being capacitatively coupled into a ungrounded shielded cable. The noise is greatly attenuated by grounding the shield. In this example, the 2V goes into essentially an open circuit, so the noise will be lower voltage if there is a load.

Comment: That's the issue, the AC conductors are not routed together. They are at almost the same potential, so I'm not concerned with capacitive coupling, but I'll calculate that separately. The DC line is low powered so impedance may be an issue there.

Comment: If the DC lines are close, that will likewise reduce the mutual inductance inductance.

Answer (score 1):

If you twist the wires then it's all a question of how balanced you keep it.

There is an error in your calculation, it is the flux through the area **between** your two DC conductors that induces the voltage.  You can determine the mutual inductance by considering:

[image]

and then the mutual inductance is given by:

[image]

if \$w<<s\$ then \$M \approx \frac{\mu_0 l w}{2\pi s}\$

and so the induced voltage in the loop is \$V = j\omega M I\$
(possibly with a sign error - I haven't checked)

When you twist the wires you effectively get a lot of loops that add up +/- and tend to cancel out. If the twist pitch is perfectly constant, the spacing between the twisted conductors constant, the spacing to the AC wire is constant, and you have an even number of reversals, then ideally there is no coupling.

Try to estimate some worst-case left over unbalanced area and see if the voltage you calculate is a problem.  Alternatively, measure it.  If it is a problem, try to improve the geometry, move it further away, go to a co-ax arrangement if possible (the geometry here is much better balanced).

Images and mutual inductance calculation from: http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/notes/modules/guide11.pdf

**Edit in response to comment:**

The way that twisting tends to produce induced voltages that cancel is hopefully illustrated with the following rough diagram:

[image]

You can see that if you had the lines parallel for a while then quickly swapped them over for the same length then swapped them back, that you would have two loops that would have equal voltages, but opposite in sign, so would cancel.  Twisting achieves the same thing, but the swapping is more gradual.

Comment: "twist the wires you effectively get a lot of loops", Could you please explain about the loop? I thought loop is made when the current can pass along the loop.

Comment: _"flux through the area between your two DC conductors that induces the voltage"_ Thanks! If the conductors have 0.5 mm isolation and are pressed against each other, 1 mm still gives the correct value. I'll update my question though.

Comment: Actually, there is nearly no voltage along the wire. The effects of twisting are better explained by the inversion of the area versor: instead of a big area A intercepting flux, you have many approx equal areas of alternatively opposite sign Stokes normal that produce a cancellation of the effect of the variable magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! It is an interesting analysis. I will just borrow you calculation.

Twist or not matters only how far the pair of victim wires are,to each other, and relative distance to the noise source.

If one was 5 cm apart from the line, and another was 5.1 cm away, then the difference on the two victim wires is: **dE = 1.5mV x (1 - 0.05 / 0.051) = 29uV / meter**.

Problem occurs when that, dE, appears as "differential noise" on the sensitive signal. Thus, twisting the victim wire cancels the noise by alternating dE on both wires, remaining only common mode noise. The degree of twist depends on the noise frequency. For 60Hz, a loose twist will be fine, unless the load switches with sharp edge. Twisting works for capacitive coupling as well.

---

Edited, 
How many twists? Intuitively say; it is related to the wavelength of the source noise. For 60 hz line frequency, loose twist is fine. Meantime, tighter twist will give more freedom to the routing of wires, no need for straight line.

Comment: Thanks! What would be a good starting point for how much twist is twisted enough? 5 turns/meter?

Comment: @winny probably [Belden](https://www.belden.com/) has good resources. I would use what is available from search (twisted pair 18 awg). If you are drill twisting,... how about 2 twists per 3 inches? It is just a random number I picked while looking at my caliper.

Comment: @winny I found! Check page 6 of [this doc.](https://g3ynh.info/zdocs/refs/NBS/Rosa1908.pdf) by [Edward Bennett Rosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Bennett_Rosa),   calculating mutual inductance of two straight line.